# Using A Dictionary To Hash <String,Class>

Tags: c#, dictionary, unity-game-engine

I am looking to do a specific task for a small unity game I am doing for class.
In it, I am trying to hash a class that contains variables and a method that is specific to each class created for the dictionary. The variables work fine as they do not need to be static and are not abstract, the method however I am struggling to work with.

Here is my entire script being used.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Reflection;
using UnityEngine;

public class EnemyZ : MonoBehaviour
{
    // Class used to hash names health assets and then move options
    public class EnemySet
    {
        public string EnemyName { get; set; }
        public float EnemyHealth { get; set; }
        public void Moves()
        {

        }
    }

    //setting EnemySet with names health (assets and move options)
    public static void Setup()
    {
        var cards = new Dictionary<string, EnemySet>()
        {
            { "Slime", new EnemySet { EnemyName="Slime", EnemyHealth= 25} },
            { "Flaz", new EnemySet { EnemyName="Flaz", EnemyHealth= 34} },
            { "BandShee", new EnemySet { EnemyName="BandShee", EnemyHealth= 45} },
            {"Fan-Natic", new EnemySet{EnemyName = "Fan-Natic", EnemyHealth = 20} }
        };
    }

    void Update()
    {

    }
}
```

I am looking to have the `Move` function be overridden and callable.
How would I set this dictionary of class/method's up and how would I call it once it has been correctly added to the dictionary?

Comment: you might be able to call a generic update method with different values to its argument depending on who is calling it

Comment: (1) you aren't storing your dictionary anywhere. You're creating a local variable, putting some stuff in it, and then throwing it on the ground. (2) `cards["Slime"].Move()`?

Comment: It's not clear to me what you mean by "I am trying to hash a class" - could you clarify that please?

Comment: @spawns, I don't think you're hashing a class at all, the hash function only occurs on the Key in the dictionary not the Value.   Additionally from your layout, it looks like you want to create a different type so really you should be, creating a class for each type of enemy and overring their moves in code, then in the dictionary, you provide the overrided class instead of the base class `EnemySet`

Answer (score 1):

I think you are approaching your class structure and the approach to overwriting your abstract methods incorrectly which is causing the confusion around the dictionary.

I would create an interface for enemies that defines what your enemies need to contain and perform. You can then create an abstract base class the implements common functionality for enemies. Each enemy type should then inherit from your base class.

See below as an example:

```
// all enemy types must implement the following
public interface IEnemy {
    string EnemyName { get; }
    float EnemyHealth { get; }
    void Move ();
}

// abstract base class for common functionality
public abstract class Enemy : IEnemy {
    protected float speed = 0.1f;

    public string EnemyName { get; protected set; }
    public float EnemyHealth { get; protected set; }

    public virtual void Move () {
        Debug.Log ($"{EnemyName} moving at {speed}");
    }
}

public class Slime : Enemy {
    public Slime () {
        speed = 0.1f;
        EnemyName = "Slimer";
        EnemyHealth = 100f;
    }

    public override void Move () {
        Debug.Log ($"{EnemyName} moving at {speed}");
    }
}

public class Flaz : Enemy {
    public Flaz () {
        speed = 0.5f;
        EnemyName = "Flaz";
        EnemyHealth = 50f;
    }

    public override void Move () {
        Debug.Log ($"{EnemyName} moving at {speed}");
    }
}

public class Test : MonoBehaviour {
    readonly List<IEnemy> Enemies = new List<IEnemy> ();

    void Start () {
        var slimer = new Slime ();
        Debug.Log ($"{slimer.EnemyName} initialized with health of {slimer.EnemyHealth}");
        slimer.Move ();

        var flaz = new Flaz ();
        Debug.Log ($"{flaz.EnemyName} initialized with health of {flaz.EnemyHealth}");
        flaz.Move ();

        Enemies.Add (slimer);
        Enemies.Add (flaz);

        Debug.Log ($"Added {Enemies.Count} enemies");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
I'd say that having a better understanding of classes and interfaces would be good if you wanted to store your enemies in code (the easy way if you're good at object oriented code).
```

However to answer the question directly I'm going to assume that you're loading enemies from a database or a file or some other non-code format.

In that case I'd go with something like

```
// Class used to hash names health assets and then move options
public class EnemySet
{
    public string EnemyName { get; set; }
    public float EnemyHealth { get; set; }
    public Action Moves { get; set; }
}
```

Then when ever you are reading from your datasource to set up the dictionary of enemies I'd have something like

```
public class EnemyLoader
{
    public void MovePawn() => console.WriteLine("I'm a chess piece");
    public void MoveZombie() => console.WriteLine("Brains");
    public void MoveSlime() => console.WriteLine("Wobbo");

    public Action PickMovement(string moveType)
    {
        switch(moveType)
        {
            case "pawn": return MovePawn;
            case "pawn": return MoveZombie;
            default: return MoveSlime;
        }
    }

    public Dictionary<string, EnemySet> LoadEnemies()
    {
        var dataSource = ReadDataFromSomewhere();
        return dataSource.ToDictionary(
            k => k.EnemyName,
            v => new EnemySet
            {
               EnemyName = v.EnemyName,
               EnemySpeed = v.EnemySpeed,
               Move = PickMovement(v.MoveType)
            });
    }
}
```